# Can a function have two different functions as its integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I integrated the given function in the image above and I got the $ \tan^{-1} (2\sin^{2}x-1)+ c $ (where c is arbitrary constant ) by method of substitution (taking $ \sin^{2}x=t $ where $dt = \sin 2x dx$) but the answer given in the textbook is $ \tan^{-1}(\tan^{2}x) $, this also by method of substitution (taking $ \tan^{2}x = t $ and $
  dt=\tan( x ) \sec^{2}(x) dx $ )

now i differentiated both of these functions and i got the original function but i am unable to apprehend how $ 2\sin^{2}x-1 = \tan^{2}x $

Comment: Short answer: YES. A function has infinitely many antiderivatives. Evidently those two functions differ by a constant, not necessarily being the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the difference between the two solutions. And, for simplicity, look at the tangent of the difference. We are going to use $$\tan(a-b)=\frac{\tan a-\tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b}$$
and $$\tan{\arctan a}=a$$
Therefore
$$\tan(\mathrm{difference})=\tan\left(\arctan(\tan^2 x)-\arctan(2\sin^2x-1)\right)=\frac{\tan^2x-(2\sin^2 x-1)}{1+\tan^2x(2\sin^2x-1)}$$
Now we multiply both numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 x$
$$\tan(\mathrm{difference})=\frac{\sin^2x-2\sin^2x\cos^2x+\cos^2x}{\cos^2x+\sin^2x(2\sin^2x-1)}\\=\frac{1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}{1+\sin^2x(2\sin^2x-2)}\\=\frac{1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}{1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x}=1$$
I've used $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$.
So the difference is then $$\mathrm{difference}=\arctan 1=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: $\tan c=1$ does not imply $c=\pi/4$ (only $\bmod\pi$) so I think some argument (like the one in my answer) is missing here.

Comment: @AnneBauval indeed. Since both terms are in the $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ interval, a possible answer is also $c=-3\pi/4$

Comment: Whence my comment. But have a look at [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4683030/386889) (which was only a few seconds before yours).

Answer (score 2):

Note that

\begin{align}
&\ \tan^{-1}(\tan^2x)-\tan^{-1}(2\sin^2x-1)\\
=& \ \tan^{-1}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1+\cos 2x}+\tan^{-1}(\cos2x)\\
=&\ \tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1+\cos 2x}+\cos2x}{1-\cos2x\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1+\cos 2x}}=\tan^{-1}1=\frac\pi4
\end{align}
So, they differ by a constant.

Comment: $\arctan x+\arctan y$ is not always equal to $\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$ (it is sometimes $+\pi$ or $-\pi$) so I think some argument is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the graphic of $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(2 \sin^2 x -1) - \tan^{-1}(\tan^2 x)$. What can you guess from this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\tan^{-1}(\tan^2x)\in[0,\pi/2)$ and $b=\tan^{-1}(2\sin^2x-1)\in[-\pi/4,\pi/4].$ Then,

$$a-b\in[-\pi/4,3\pi/4)$$

and

$$\tan(a-b)=\frac{\tan^2x-(2\sin^2x-1)}{1+(\tan^2x)(2\sin^2x-1)}=1$$

hence $$a-b=\frac\pi4.$$

Comment: In principle, if $a\in [0,\pi/2)$ and $b\in [-\pi/4,\pi/4]$, the minimum value of $a-b$ can be negative, for example for $a=0$, $b=\pi/4$, $a-b=-\pi/4$.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, I correct my misprint. @Andrei